# Nvidia 384.111 driver upate: Login/password prompt disappears

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia

Using:

```
sudo apt update
```

.. brought in an update to `nvidia 384.111`

Next reboot made no login and password prompt appear, just the background image. Attempts to access text mode console, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> appeared dead (nothing happened). So in the end I had to hold the power button for 5 seconds - to get the computer turn off.

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure to get access to a root shell;

Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> as the computer BIOS screen closes, some say that holding a <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key also works, to get access to the grub boot menus. In there you can navigate to an option that reads "recovery console" - and press RETURN to run it.
*(at the recovery console, select to run `fsck` and then activate networking, before dropping to root shell - press enter one extra time to actually get the shell prompt! - this is the easy way, you don't have to remember any commands to get through)*

Alternatively you might have luck and get a text mode login prompt if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> during the text mode boot (press <kbd>esc</kbd> to reveal it)... before the login gui appears. You will probably have to be quick to succeed with this though.

After login from text mode prompt; type these commands and keep an eye open for error messages. If something fails here, I suggest using a text mode browser (links, lynx, ...) to google the error(s).

Here is what I did to get back to a GPU-driven GUI:

When checking with `dpkg --list | grep nvidia` it did show:

```
ii  nvidia-361                                                 
367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-367 ii  nvidia-367                                 
375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-375 ii  nvidia-375                                 
384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                     amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-384 ii  nvidia-384                                 
384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 384.111 rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-361             
367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-367 rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-367           
375.39-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-375 rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-375           
384.90-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                      amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-opencl-icd-384 ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-384           
384.111-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                     amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD ii  nvidia-prime                                           
0.8.2                                        amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime ii  nvidia-settings                             
361.42-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Which shows **a hive** of different nvidia drivers all installed at the same time... I went on with uninstalling all of them, and then attempt to reinstall the previous version:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install nvidia-375 # makes 384.111 emerge *sigh*
```

... but as you see in the comment; that still brought in the "latest and greatest" version.

Instead of giving up at this point, I gave it a try...

```
sudo reboot
```

... and the login prompt came up!

Now, leaving it like this might have disable auto-updates, (as the nvidia-375 package was specified explicitly). That remains to be seen though.