# Nvidia 384.111 driver install fails on 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am unable to install the latest Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 on Linux 4.13.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384 nvidia-384-dev
```

I get this error, which completely ruins my entire Monday:

```
Removing old nvidia-384-384.111 DKMS files...
Loading new nvidia-384-384.111 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: nvidia-384-384.111
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-384 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
```

Here is the [full output dump](http://cloud.jchook.com/3F2P003z1o1U/install.log).

I did find a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-384/+bug/1737752) but it appears to be only for 4.15 kernels. Do I need to open a new bug report on launchpad?

I am able to install the 384.111 driver using the .run file downloaded from Nvidia's website. However, I want to use `apt-get` for install.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: At least related: https://askubuntu.com/a/994401/289138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found the issue.

When **un**installing the 1000 nvidia/cuda/cudnn packages, dpkg wont actually remove dkms (Dynamic Kernel Module System) files located in `/var/lib/dkms`.

Mind boggling that you are required to simply know/intuit this, but Linux demands this of you.

This command solved the problem for me:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dkms
```

After this the normal `sudo apt-get install nvidia-384` command executed as expected since `dkms` didn't fail along the way.

Comment: You should be careful with that, as that command will delete the entire dkms directory, which will (could) cause problems the next time there's a kernel update/upgrade. For example, if you have installed VirtualBox, the VirtualBox dkms module will also be in /var/lib/dkms, so VirtualBox will break when your kernel is updated. The correct thing to do would be `$ sudo dkms remove nvidia/384.111 --all`

Comment: good point, though I tried that command at least 10 times and also checked to make sure nvidia was the only thing in the directory first.